# Equivalent of pre-pull hooks for data syncing on Github

Tags: git, github, amazon-s3

I have a dataset on AWS S3 which is constantly being updated by other people. After I pull the latest changes from our repository on Github, I'd like to automatically update my local files with the latest data from S3.

It doesn't seem like there are pre-pull hooks, but is there a simple way to set up the sort of automatic behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any tool/Service which might connect S3 and git the way you need it.

Maybe you can write a small script which will contain below two commands to perform what you need :

```
git pull
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name> .
```